# Why is this astronaut placing a radar reflector?

Tags: space-shuttle, eva

In [this video](https://youtu.be/P5_GlAOCHyE?t=16m25s) we can see an astronaut on the payload bay of the Space Shuttle, placing what looks like a [radar reflector](http://www.google.com/images?q=radar%20reflector), during an [EVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extravehicular_activity). The following image is a frame from the video in question:

[image: astronaut placing radar reflector]

[Radar reflectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_reflector) have many applications. They are usually mounted on small boats to increase their radar fingerprint ([source](http://ir.library.oregonstate.edu/xmlui/bitstream/handle/1957/25224/SGNO411978.pdf?seq)), and they are part of the emergency equipment on board a lifeboat.([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifeboat_(shipboard)))

However, I had no idea that they were used on board spacecraft, so I find it very intriguing.

- Why is this astronaut placing a radar reflector?
- Are radar reflectors used consistently during
  space missions or was this just part of an experiment?
- Can anybody identify which [STS mission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Space_Shuttle_missions#Launches_and_orbital_flights) this was?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This was mission [STS-61B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-61-B). The giveaways are the ACCESS payload box and the Mexico logo on the PAM-D sunshield.

The last task of the first EVA was to deploy a small satellite  (the radar reflector) to be used for station-keeping experiments.

Ironically, the shuttle radar was failed, so the targetting was all done visually.

This was definitely part of an experiment; I am not aware of radar reflectors being used "consistently", at least in the shuttle program.

Here is [Woody Spring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherwood_C._Spring) deploying the satellite/reflector (a few frames after the picture in the question)

[image]

[source](https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=28098.180) (scroll down past the pictures to get to the text)

Comment: So this footage dates back to 1985! Amazing! The link that you provided has very good information about the mission events. Interesting story. Thank you.

Comment: By "deploying" is it safe to assume he simply "dropped" it into space at that altitude?  Or was it attached to some other satellite piece?

Comment: It seems that the reflector *was* the satellite. More info at the link in the answer.

Comment: @SarahBailey Yes, that's correct. Astronaut Woody Spring released the radar reflector into space orbiting completely free, in fact, it stayed about eighty days in orbit. For comparison, the STS-61B mission only lasted 6 days and 21 hours.